# How to only allow admin users to create accounts in an ASP.NET core (with individual authentication) project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating a website using ASP.NET core with MVC where a few people will have accounts to manage a database. Since anonymous users will be able to view the website, I don't want them to be allowed to create accounts and mess stuff up. I'm not sure if adding the `[Authorize(policy)]` attribute to the create account page is possible since the ASP.NET core template hides the page that I need to add it too. Is there a way I could do it? Now that I'm thinking about it, does *individual* authentication even allow you to do such a thing?

Before you say this is a duplicate question, I've looked through previous answers only to find that they just add `[Authorize]` to the create account page, which I said I'm fairly certain I can't do. Unless there is something I missed, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back and think about what you are saying. You want to enforce authorization on anonymous users. Does that make sense to you? How can you authorize someone you don't know?

If you don't want anyone to be able to create accounts, your action simply cannot be exposed to anonymous users. You should **remove the code generated by the template** or at the very least, hide it behind an authorization scheme like the other answers have suggested.

That leaves you with the problem of how to create a user when the page to create a user cannot be accessed. I've dealt with this in a couple of ways in the past:

1. Create a user with admin rights programmatically (if it doesn't already exist) on **application start**. This user is authorized to access a page within the app (usually an admin panel on a **separate Area**) where he/she can create other users. You use this account to grant access to other accounts and assign proper roles as needed. OR,
2. Have the application check for initialization on start up and if it hasn't done it before, show a workflow that allows you to create an admin account (kind of like a first time installation step). Once created, you use it the same way as in option 1.

In both cases, you will be applying the `Authorize` attribute to your controllers and/or actions as desired and will need an "admin" facility where users with proper rights can manage things.

Comment: I don't want to 'enforce authorisation on anonymous users,' I want to disallow anonymous users from creating an account. They should be allowed to log in if they have the credentials for an 'admin' account. Maybe I just worded my question poorly.

Comment: How would I go about 'removing the code generated by the template?' That sounds like something that could help greatly.

Comment: @DiseasedFinger remove it as in **delete it**.

Comment: Where do I find them?

Comment: @DiseasedFinger it's the account controller action to which you are trying to apply the `Authorize` attribute. You need to either block access in this manner or move it to an administration area but you can't leave it open.